# displaying the lowest and highest of 2d array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to display the lowest and the highest value. The highest value is correct but the smallest is always giving me 0 can you help me.

```
package openlink.domain;

import java.io.*;

public class table2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int table1[][] = new int[5][5];
        int table2[][] = new int[5][5];
        int table3[][] = new int[5][5];
        int i, j, k, l, b, c, g, p, num = 0, num1 = 0, small = 0, largest = 0;
        String input = " ";
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                table1[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
        for (k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
            for (l = 0; l < 5; l++) {
                table2[k][l] = 0;
            }
        }
        try {
            for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                    System.out.print("Input table1[" + i + "][" + j + "]= ");
                    input = in.readLine();
                    num = Integer.parseInt(input);
                    table1[i][j] = num;
                }
            }
            for (k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
                for (l = 0; l < 5; l++) {
                    System.out.print("Input table2[" + k + "][" + l + "]= ");
                    input = in.readLine();
                    num1 = Integer.parseInt(input);
                    table2[k][l] = num1;
                }
            }
            for (b = 0; b < table3.length; b++) {
                for (c = 0; c < table3.length; c++) {

                    table3[b][c] = table2[b][c] + table1[b][c];
                }
            }
            System.out.println("table1");
            for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                    System.out.print(table1[i][j] + "  ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("table2");
            for (k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
                for (l = 0; l < 5; l++) {
                    System.out.print(table2[k][l] + "  ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("table3");
            /* this is the code in how to locate the lowest and the highest */
            for (b = 0; b < 5; b++) {
                for (c = 0; c < 5; c++) {
                    System.out.print(table3[b][c] + "  ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println();
            for (b = 0; b < table1.length; b++) {
                for (c = 0; c < table2.length; c++) {
                    if (small > table3[b][c]) {
                        small = table3[b][c];
                    } else if (table3[b][c] > largest) {
                        largest = table3[b][c];
                    }

                }
            }
            System.out.println("the highest value in table3: " + largest);
            System.out.println("the lowest value in table3: " + small);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

please help me  here

Comment: A few points to get you started: Please use an IDE to format your code. Variables named as i, j, k, l, b, etc. make it very hard to follow the code. Have you worked with a debugger before?

Comment: assign a value of small and large from the array before calculating smallest and largest number

Answer (score 6):

Well, you've initialized `small` as 0 to start with... so you're only going to update it if there are negative numbers. Likewise you've initialized `large` as 0, so you'll only update that if there are *positive* numbers. Enter all-negative numbers and you'll find that `small` is right and `large` is wrong.

It would be better to initialize `small` and large as `table3[0][0]` to start with, so you *know* they're each a valid value from the array.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies within

```
    if (small > table3[b][c]) {
                    small = table3[b][c];
                } else if (table3[b][c] > largest) {
                    largest = table3[b][c];
                }
```

Since small is initialized as 0, it will never be larger than table3[b][c]
Try initalizing small with a large number and it should work just fine.

On a side note: Your code needs some cleanup. Your variables need more telling names and you do not have to declare every variable for each for loop at the top.
Try to replace:

```
    for (k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
            for (l = 0; l < 5; l++) {
                System.out.print("Input table2[" + k + "][" + l + "]= ");
                input = in.readLine();
                num1 = Integer.parseInt(input);
                table2[k][l] = num1;
            }
        }
```

with

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                System.out.print("Input table2[" + i + "][" + j + "]= ");
                input = in.readLine();
                num1 = Integer.parseInt(input);
                table2[i][j] = num1;
            }
        }
```

You can also extract this to a method just by doing the following:

```
private int[][] getFilledArray(int size, String arrayName) {
int[][] myArray = new int[size][size];

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String input = new String();

try {
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < myArray[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print("Input " + arrayName + "[" + i + "][" + j + "]= ");

        input = in.readLine();

        myArray[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(input);
    }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return myArray;
}
```